# Sending Stomp CONNECT Frame to ApolloMQ using Scala

Tags: scala, stomp, apollo

I am currently trying to send a CONNECT Stomp frame to an ApolloMQ broker using Scala.  I am doing the following:

```
val socketChannel: SocketChannel = SocketChannel.open
val socketAddress: SocketAddress = new InetSocketAddress("localhost", 61613)
val frame = "CONNECT\naccept-version:1.0,1.1,1.2\nhost:localhost\n" +
            "login:username\npasscode:password\n\n\0".toCharArray
val byteArray = frame.map { c => c.asInstanceOf[Byte] }
val bb = ByteBuffer.allocate(128)
bb.put(byteArray)
```

If I then try to connect and write

```
socketChannel.connect(socketAddress)
socketChannel.write(bb)
```

It seems to write, but nothing is returned and the connection is disconnected right away.  If I rewind the `ByteBuffer` first

```
bb.rewind
socketChannel.connect(socketAddress)
socketChannel.write(bb)
```

it looks like the connection is hitting Apollo, but the following is thrown

```
java.net.ProtocolException: The maximum command length was exceeded
```

I have searched around, but am unable to find any information as to why this seems to be happening.

Answer (score 1):

To covert from a string to a ByteBuffer, try doing a simpler:

```
val bb = ByteBuffer.wrap(frame.getBytes("UTF-8"))
```